# Run a perl script on remote machine from local machine using Telnet or SSH with Perl

Tags: perl, ssh, telnet

I want to run a Perl script in a remote machine using telnet or ssh.  The script is on my local host.how can do this.  Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 4):

If you for some reason don't want to copy the script to the remote host and then run it, you can send the script to the Perl interpreter over stdin. If perl doesn't get either a script name of a script on the command line it tries to read the script on stdin. So this would work:

```
ssh user@remote perl < my_script.pl
```

Of course this requires that all necessary modules are already installed on the remote host. If you script only have pure perl dependencies you can work around this restriction by using [App::FatPacker](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?App%3A%3AFatPacker) to make your script (more) self contained.

But if this is an recurring task I would recommend getting the script deployed correctly to your remote host.

Answer (score 1):

```
scp your script to remote machine.
ssh user@remote 'perl /path/to/remote/script.pl'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using HERE document across SSH might also do the trick you are after. You can run at least a BASH script without first separately copying it to remote. I have not verified anything else than BASH but no reason to doubt either.  Please see:

[ssh + here document + interactive mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995148/ssh-here-document-interactive-mode)