# ssh + here document + interactive mode

Tags: bash, ssh

Can I run a here document script over ssh on remote machine with interactive mode?

Code example is:

```
ssh -t xijing@ggzshop.com 'bash -s' <<EOF
sudo ls
......Other big scripts......
EOF
```

### double -t won't work properly as well.

-----------------------------One possible solution:-------------------

After a lot of tries, I come up with following answers:

```
Script=`cat <<'EOF'
sudo ls
.....Big scripts.....
EOF`

ssh -t user@host ${Script}
```

which will allow user to type password in.

Comment: Appears to work fine when no `sudo` is used.

Comment: Probably will only work if the remote host is set up to allow password-less sudo for user `xijing` , but none of my hosts are set up that way, so I can't test (you host ggzshop probably can't / shouldn't be set up that way, either). Just skip the sudo part and ssh to the host as the "correct" user with permission to those files (which should _not_ be root).

Comment: @michael_n I would like to issue some commands like: sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart. and similar admin tasks. which requires the sudo command, if no other way to do it, I have to transfer script to remote first, I think.

Comment: @xijingdai that is a simpler case that doesn't require the messy "here" document (as you're recent update shows), `ssh -t user@host 'sudo /sbin/service apache2 start'` (or whatever) (the "-t" masks the passwd, but isn't otherwise necessary)... another alternative I noticed (but not tried) is [sshsudo](http://code.google.com/p/sshsudo/) (requires [sshpass](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/), available via apt-get on ubuntu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution of Xijing appears to work ok for me. However, I did a couple of cosmetic changes. First, for readability I used "dollar-parentheses" instead of backticks. For another thing I don't offer any explanation: Semicolons were needed to separate multiple commands in Script snippet even though commands are written on separate lines. My test:

```
Script=$( cat <<'HERE'
hostname;
cat /etc/issue;
sudo id
HERE
)

ssh -t user@host ${Script}
```

Sudo password will be asked in a normal manner, no need to omit that.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think you can run interactive scripts like that.

To achieve what you want, you could create dedicated users for your common admin tasks that can run admin commands with `sudo` without password. Next, setup ssh key authentication to login as the dedicated users and perform the necessary tasks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to use semicolons to separate multiple commands in `Script` if there are quotes around it.

```
Script="$( cat <<'HERE'
hostname;
cat /etc/issue;
sudo id
HERE
)"


- ssh -t user@host ${Script}
+ ssh -t user@host "${Script}"

# alternative (not recommended)
# set IFS variable to null string to avoid deletion of newlines \n in unquoted variable expansion
export IFS=''
ssh -t user@host ${Script}
```